# Open a modal window and redirect to a new page with one link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I would like to be able to open a jQuery UI Dialog and redirect to a new page onclick of a single link.  Is there a way to do this?

Here is my dialog handler:

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialogDiv" ).dialog({position:['middle',60],
            open: function(event, ui) {  
            jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html('<span style="float:right;"><img src="../images/x.png" /></span>');  
        },  
            dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow',
            modal: true,    
            autoOpen: false,
            width: '950px',
            close: function(ev, ui) {$(this).close();}
        });

        $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialogDiv" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
        $( ".btnDone" ).click(function(){
            $('.ui-dialog-content').dialog( "close" );
        })
    });
```

And this is the link I am currently using (it opens the modal window fine, but doesn't redirect to the page):

```
<a href="newpage.html" class="button opener">View</a>
<div style="display:none;" id="dialogDiv" title="Your custom page">
</p>Here is your new custom dashboard</p>
<br />
<a href="#" class="btnDone button">OK</a>
</div>
```

So when the user clicks the "View" button, they will see the new page loaded in the background and the modal dialog on top of it.  How do I adjust my code to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/tURMc/1/

You can probably use a iframe and show the pop up and iframe will load the href url. So, the popup will open up and the required page will open up in the iframe.

HTML Change:-

```
<iframe id="testiframe" height="400" width="400" border="0"></iframe>
```

JS Change:-

```
$(".opener").click(function () {
        $("#dialogDiv").dialog("open");
        $("#testiframe").attr("src",$(this).attr("href"));
        return false;
    });
```